# Unable to connect a button to wkwebview in Xcode objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I am working on fixing some old script. Apple wants me to use WKWebview for my social links. I am trying to add WKWebview to each social link and open it up within the app. How do I link a button to my code?

Here's my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/sfneonline"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURl];
    [webView loadRequest:myRequest];
}

- (void)loadView {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *webConfiguration = [WKWebViewConfiguration init];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:webConfiguration];
    webView.UIDelegate = self;
    self.view = webView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *webConfiguration = [WKWebViewConfiguration init];
```

It should be created with `[WKWebViewConfiguration new]` or `[[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]`

Besides, why didn't you use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) to show a link within your app?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/sfneonline"];
SFSafariViewController *safariController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];

[self presentViewController:safariController animated:YES completion:nil];
    // or
[self.navigationController pushViewController:safariController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much

Comment: Now I am unable to connect my social media link button to it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Alexander I was not aware of SFSafariViewController